# How are functions defined for mathematical operators?

Tags: operators

Since '+', '-', and the rest of the arithmetic operators must be, at heart, just function calls (I think), how are they defined? More specifically, how are they written such that they can look for arguments that precede them and follow them?

For example, the function '*', or multiply, in the expression 7 * 9 must look for the first argument 7 before it's called, and then the 9, it's second argument, which appears to be in the right place.

Most languages (not OCaml) require parentheses around arguments -- how have they gotten around this requirement in languages that do?

Comment: In many languages, the mathematical operators are not functions.

Comment: This question is effectively *"how are languages parsed and implemented?"* and is too broad for SO.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking about operator overloading, or at least reading into operator overloading will give you a pretty solid understanding on how arithmetic operations are defined in some languages.  Here's a link to a nice tutorial on C++ operator overloading:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm

Answer (score 0):

In object-oriented world, this is called "operator overloading". It is just a kind of syntactic sugar, that enables you to call a + b, instead of a.+(b), that is actually the same method call.